# PowerShell calling function for telnet shows strange behavior

Tags: powershell, csv, foreach, telnet

I have a telnet script as function, that behaves well, if it is called directly.

If I try to call it in a loop, it starts to misbehave.

This code is working fine for me:

```
$HostList = Import-CSV ".\list.csv" -Header IP,Script,SNMP -Delimiter (";") 

ForEach ($item in $HostList)
{
    Write-Host "Connecting to: $item" -NoNewline
    $Script = Get-Content (".\Scripts\" + $item.Script + ".txt") 
    Get-Telnet -RemoteHost $item.IP -SNMPLoc $item.SNMP -Login $login -PassWord $password -Commands $Script
}
```

The following changes seems to break the script, as I want to make the contril file more dynamic:

```
$login = Read-Host 'Please provide the login? '
$password = Read-Host -AsSecureString 'Please provide the password? '
Import-CSV ".\list.csv" -Delimiter (";") | Foreach-Object { 
    [String[]] $VarValues = ""
    foreach ($item in $_.PSObject.Properties)
    {
        if ($item.Name.Contains("IP"))
        {
            $HostName = $item.Value
        }

        if ($item.Name.Contains("Script"))
        {
            $Script = Get-Content (".\Scripts\" + $item.Value + ".txt") 
        }

        if (!$item.Name.Contains("IP") -and !$item.Name.Contains("Script")) 
        {
            $VarValues += $item.Name + "#" + $item.Value
        }
    }

    Get-Telnet -RemoteHost $HostName -Login $login -PassWord $password -Commands $Script -Vars $VarValues
}
```

If I call Get-Telnet the function on is own, it's still working.

As I don't known, how many possible columns might be in the control file (.\list.csv), is there any other way, to create $VarValues list from the file?

Comment: I recommend you use `if`, `elseif`, and `else`; or alternatively `switch` to handle your conditions. Are you getting any errors with the script? Or is it just failing silently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed it to >

```
$data = Import-CSV $ControlFile -Delimiter (";")
$OutputPath = $OutputPath + "%{0}.txt"
Clear-Host
foreach ($obj in $data) 
{
    [String[]] $VarValues = ""
    foreach ($item in $obj.psobject.properties)
    {
        $Key = $item.name
        $Value = $item.value

        switch ($Key)
        {
            "IP" { $HostName = $Value }
            "Script" { $Script = Get-Content ($ScriptPath + $Value + ".txt") }
            default { $VarValues += $Key + "#" + $Value }
        }
    }
    Get-Telnet -RemoteHost $HostName -Login $login -PassWord $password -Commands $Script -Vars $VarValues
}
```

That seems to do the trick and the idea to use switch makes things even easier.

Something might be off with the W2K itself - as soon as the pipe is gone - all goes well.